# php jstree how to load children from database only when i click the parent to expand

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jstree

I am creating a jstree to categorize all data of the database and show it in an ajax tree. I hope I can create a jstree that the children only load from database when I click the parent to expand to reduce the time to load the page at the beginning. The following is the code I used to create the jstree. How to modify the code so that I can create a jstree that only load children nodes when I click the parent nodes to expand?

This is the code I used to show the jstree.

```
$('#ajax').jstree({
    'core' : {
        'data' : {
            "url" : "<?php echo $weburls; ?>loadtree.php",
            "dataType" : "json" 
        }
    }
});
```

This is the code I used to load data into an array and pass to the jstree.

```
//insert parents into array
$resultProj = getResult("SELECT DISTINCT parents FROM table WHERE parents IS NOT NULL ");
for($i2=0;$i2<sizeOf($resultProj);$i2++){
    $dresult[$i2]['id']= $i2+1;
    $dresult[$i2]['name']=$resultProj[$i2]['parents'];
    $dresult[$i2]['text']=$resultProj[$i2]['parents'];
    $dresult[$i2]['parent_id']='0';
    $ddresult[$i2]['id']= $i2+1;
    $ddresult[$i2]['name']=$resultProj[$i2]['parents'];
}
$i3=sizeOf($dresult);
$i4=sizeOf($dresult);

//insert childrens into array
foreach($ddresult as $dresult2){
    $resultcust = getResult("SELECT no, name FROM table WHERE parents='" . $dresult2['name'] . "'");
    $i5=0;
    for($i3;$i3<(sizeOf($resultcust)+$i4);$i3++){
        $dresult[$i3]['id']=$resultcust[$i5]['no'];
        $dresult[$i3]['name']=$resultcust[$i5]['name'];
        $dresult[$i3]['text']=$resultcust[$i5]['name'];
        $dresult[$i3]['parent_id']=$dresult2['id'];
        $i5++;
    }
    $i3=sizeOf($dresult);
    $i4=sizeOf($dresult);
}

$itemsByReference = array();
// Build array of item references:
foreach($dresult as $key => &$item) {
   $itemsByReference[$item['id']] = &$item;
   // Children array:
   $itemsByReference[$item['id']]['children'] = array();
   // Empty data class (so that json_encode adds "data: {}" ) 
   $itemsByReference[$item['id']]['dresult'] = new StdClass();
}

// Set items as children of the relevant parent item.
foreach($dresult as $key => &$item)
if($item['parent_id'] && isset($itemsByReference[$item['parent_id']]))
  $itemsByReference [$item['parent_id']]['children'][] = &$item;

// Remove items that were added to parents elsewhere:
foreach($dresult as $key => &$item) {
if($item['parent_id'] && isset($itemsByReference[$item['parent_id']]))
  unset($dresult[$key]);
}
echo json_encode( $dresult );
```

Comment: Looks like you're using jstree: try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31967836/2181514

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load children on demand with new jstree v3.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928498/how-to-load-children-on-demand-with-new-jstree-v3-0-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to lazy load nodes for a particular parent is to to fetch only the child nodes through your REST API. For each request you have to pass a node id with your AJAX call. So you will need an additional data callback in the jstree config which attaches the node id to your request.

```
$('#ajax').jstree({
    'core' : {
        'data' : {
            "url" : "<?php echo $weburls; ?>loadtree.php",
            "data" : function (node) {
                if(node.id === '#'){ return; }
                return { 'id': node.id };
            }
        }
    }
});
```

So the url's generated might look somewhat like this

Fetch children for Root node - *myservice.com/loadtree.php*

Fetch children for Child1 - *myservice.com/loadtree.php?id=child1*

Note: It is important that the id's generated for the node be unique throughout the entire tree structure.

Comment: Thanks, the answer you provided works well for me without `if(node.id === '#'){return;)}`.